# library for reporting error messages, crashes, anomalies

Tags: android

I would like to know if it exists and how to implement some library to be included in my android app that tells me  logcat and send via email for the bug reports  to my app. Thanks

Comment: Google Play already provides the logcat for crashes. You can see these in your Developer Console.

Comment: what do you think of Acra? http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 2):

ACRA is open source and allows you to do what you want: https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Crittercism for that. [www.crittercism.com](http://www.crittercism.com)